# Proof for binomial series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need to prove:

$(1+z)^{\alpha }=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\binom{\alpha }{k}z^{k}$ 
for $|z|$<1 and  $\alpha$ in

1) $\mathbb{N}$

2) $\mathbb{Z}$

I managed to prove it for natural $\alpha$ (by induction) but don't know how to do it for $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. I don't know how to cope with negative binomial coefficients.

Furthermore I need to show that the equation above is true for 
$x $ in $ \mathbb{R}: |x| <1 $ and $\alpha=1/p$ (p in $\mathbb{N})$ and also for $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{Q}$

I'm thankful for every hint or push in the right direction you can give me!

Comment: What do you define the combination when $k>\alpha$ and $\alpha<0$?

Comment: You will need to know something about multiplication of infinite series. See this blog post: http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part-2.html

Answer (score 1):

For $\alpha=0$ it's clear. Now suppose that $\alpha\in -\Bbb N$. First note that:
$${1\over{1+z}}=\Sigma_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^mz^m$$
then by differentiating we have:
$${d^n{1\over{1+z}}\over{dz^n}}={{(-1)^nn!}\over{(1+z)^{n+1}}}=\Sigma_{m=n}^{\infty}n!{\binom mn}(-1)^mz^{m-n}$$
since the first $n$ terms get zero after differentiation. Therefore we obtain:
$${{1}\over{(1+z)^{n+1}}}=\Sigma_{m=n}^{\infty}{\binom mn}(-1)^{m-n}z^{m-n}=\Sigma_{m=0}^{\infty}{\binom {m+n}n}(-1)^{m}z^{m}$$
by substituting $\alpha=-n-1$ we finally get 
$$(1+z)^{\alpha}=\Sigma_{m=0}^{\infty}{\binom {m-\alpha -1}{-\alpha -1}}(-1)^{m}z^{m}=\Sigma_{m=0}^{\infty}{\binom {\alpha}{m}}z^{m}$$